# Bash script help, check permission 755 on all files in a folder

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm attempting to create a bash script where I check if all the files of a specific folder (/tmp) have the permission 755. I also need it to delete all the files that don't have permission value 755.

I've attempted this so far with no luck:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in 'ls' 
do 
if [ -perm 0755 "$filename" ] 
then echo "Files with 755 permission: $filename" 
else rm "$filename" 
fi 
done 
echo "###DONE###"
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following script should do what you want: it runs in the directory youre calling it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "###START###"
for filename in * 
do 
    if [ $(stat -c "%a" "$filename") == "755" ] 
    then 
        echo "Files with 755 permission: $filename" 
    else 
        echo "REMOVING: $filename"
        rm "$filename" 
    fi 
done 
echo "###DONE###"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your script could simply consist of:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Files with 755 permission:"
find . -perm 755
echo "Deleting all other files"
find . -not -perm 755 -delete
echo "Done"
```

Note that it will delete files from the current directory and all directories beneath it. It will also delete anything with a permission other than 755 without warning, so use carefully.